# Play Framework running Asynchronous Web Calls times out

Tags: asynchronous, playframework, websocket, playframework-2.0

I have to perform three HTTP requests from a Play Application. These calls are directed towards three subprojects of the main application. The architecture looks like this:

```
main app
|
--modules
  |
  --component1
  |
  --component2
  |
  --component3
```

each `component*` is an individual sbt subprojects.

The main class in `main app` runs this Action:

```
  def service = Action.async(BodyParsers.parse.json) { implicit request =>

    val query = request.body

    val url1 = "http://localhost:9000/one"
    val url2 = "http://localhost:9000/two"
    val url3 = "http://localhost:9000/three"

    val sync_calls = for {

      a <- ws.url(url1).withRequestTimeout(Duration.Inf).withHeaders("Content-Type"->"application/json")
        .withBody(query).get()
      b <- ws.url(url2).withRequestTimeout(Duration.Inf).withHeaders("Content-Type"->"application/json")
        .withBody(a.body).get()
      c <- ws.url(url3).withRequestTimeout(Duration.Inf).withHeaders("Content-Type"->"application/json")
        .withBody(b.body).get()
    } yield c.body

    sync_calls.map(x => Ok(x))
 }
```

The components need to be activated one after the other, so they need to be a sequence. Each of the does a spark job. However when I call the `service` action I get this error:

```
[error] application -                  

! @71og96ol6 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/automatic] ->                                                        

play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[TimeoutException: Read timeout to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 after 120000 ms]]                                                                                                           [TimeoutException: Read timeout to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 after 120000 ms]
        at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:280)       
        at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:206)                                       
        at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:160)                                             
        at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:188)                                                           
        at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:98)                       │
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:1│                
00)                                                                                                                    
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:9│            
9)                                                                                                                     
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:346)                                      
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:345)                                      
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)                                                
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Read timeout to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 after 120000 ms             
        at org.asynchttpclient.netty.timeout.TimeoutTimerTask.expire(TimeoutTimerTask.java:43)                         
        at org.asynchttpclient.netty.timeout.ReadTimeoutTimerTask.run(ReadTimeoutTimerTask.java:54)                    
        at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.expire(HashedWheelTimer.java:581)                         
        at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelBucket.expireTimeouts(HashedWheelTimer.java:655)                  
        at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:367)                                        
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Length: 4931
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 25 Oct 2016 21:06:17 GMT

<body id="play-error-page">
   <p id="detail" class="pre">[TimeoutException: Read timeout to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 after 120000 ms]</p>
</body>
```

I specifically set the Timeout for each call to `Duration.Inf` for the purpose of avoiding timouts. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: The fact that it times out after 12 seconds sounds to me like play is actually timing out. ie. the controller that serves your other request runs into the play timeout rather than the one consuming it doesn't want to wait any longer.
And if that's not it, then I would look into whether your timeout `Inf` is actually being picked up. Try something like 13 seconds and then 11 seconds to verify.

Comment: Indeed you are right. I checked for both 11 and 13 secs and the error message varied accordingly. However the Duration.Inf part is recommended for that purpose by the documentation itself (and my calculations are very long so I cannot give an exact time limit). Any idea why is it not being picked up?

Comment: No I'm sorry can't really help you further. What I would do is try to debug and then report the issue with respective library directly. If you don't find anything useful, maybe just set the timeout to 9999999 or something. Maybe there's an issue with the type (eg. you're type is too big so that it wraps and the timeout that the library receives is actually negative).

Comment: @Mnemosyne Which play version are you using? 2.5?

Comment: Yes, it's 2.5. And for some reason Duration.Inf does not get recognised. I can set any hard value and it will be respected, but Inf won't.